# Curious link behaviour

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

**Why do the links in the [top answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-rounded-corners-using-css) have these title attributes?**

The entered text is:

```
 1. [CSS Design: Creating Custom Corners
    & Borders][1]
 2. [CSS Rounded Corners 'Roundup'][2]
 3. [25 Rounded Corners Techniques with CSS][3]


  [1]: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners/
  [2]: http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000044.php
  [3]: http://www.cssjuice.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/
```

But at runtime, this is the markup:

```
<ol>
<li><a title="Modern Compiler Implementation in ML" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners/">CSS Design: Creating Custom Corners
&amp; Borders</a></li>
<li><a title="Modern Compiler Implementation in Java" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000044.php">CSS Rounded Corners 'Roundup'</a></li>
<li><a title="Modern Compiler Implementation in C" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.cssjuice.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/">25 Rounded Corners Techniques with CSS</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Because SO knows what you *really* meant to say. Who would actually want to talk about CSS when there are compilers to write?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: @Justin: see the `title`.

Comment: That is *crazy* ... But I can repro it, at least on that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old server-side C# Markdown parser had some shared state issues when called multiple times.

MarkdownSharp doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might have been taken ransom by some DB/implementation change, I just edited it and the bug was no more. I couldn't reproduce it on another answer either.

As sad as it makes me, this bug will have to be swept under the rug, and likely won't come back.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro it, I see:

```
<ol>
<li><a href="http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners/" rel="nofollow">CSS Design: Creating Custom Corners
&amp; Borders</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000044.php" rel="nofollow">CSS Rounded Corners 'Roundup'</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.cssjuice.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/" rel="nofollow">25 Rounded Corners Techniques with CSS</a></li>
</ol>
```

However Voyager edited it between when you posted this question and now, so the HTML has been recompiled from the markdown.

Whatever it was is gone now.